# foreach() checking if previous was same ID

Tags: php, foreach

I have the following code:

```
foreach ( $r2->{$id}->pages as $page ) {
    echo "<br>".$page->name.":<br>";
    foreach ( $page->slots as $slot ) {
        $id = $slot->runeId;
        $details = $result->$id->{'name'};
        echo $slot->runeSlotId.": ".$slot->runeId.": ".$details;
        echo "<br>";
    }
}
```

this outputs something similar to:

```
AD ArmorHP Mix:
1: 5245: Greater Mark of Attack Damage
2: 5245: Greater Mark of Attack Damage
3: 5245: Greater Mark of Attack Damage
4: 5245: Greater Mark of Attack Damage
5: 5245: Greater Mark of Attack Damage
6: 5245: Greater Mark of Attack Damage
7: 5245: Greater Mark of Attack Damage
8: 5245: Greater Mark of Attack Damage
9: 5245: Greater Mark of Attack Damage
10: 5317: Greater Seal of Armor
11: 5317: Greater Seal of Armor
12: 5317: Greater Seal of Armor
13: 5317: Greater Seal of Armor
14: 5316: Greater Seal of Scaling Health
15: 5316: Greater Seal of Scaling Health
16: 5316: Greater Seal of Scaling Health
17: 5316: Greater Seal of Scaling Health
18: 5316: Greater Seal of Scaling Health
19: 5290: Greater Glyph of Scaling Magic Resist
20: 5290: Greater Glyph of Scaling Magic Resist
21: 5290: Greater Glyph of Scaling Magic Resist
22: 5290: Greater Glyph of Scaling Magic Resist
23: 5290: Greater Glyph of Scaling Magic Resist
24: 5290: Greater Glyph of Scaling Magic Resist
25: 5290: Greater Glyph of Scaling Magic Resist
26: 5290: Greater Glyph of Scaling Magic Resist
27: 5290: Greater Glyph of Scaling Magic Resist
28: 5335: Greater Quintessence of Attack Damage
29: 5335: Greater Quintessence of Attack Damage
30: 5335: Greater Quintessence of Attack Damage
...
1: ...
```

How would I go about checking if the previous foreach() output of `$slot->runeId` is the same as the one being output this time, and then adding a `x1 ... x2 ... x3` etc to the end of the string?

Example:

```
1: 5245: Greater Mark of Attack Damage
2: 5245: Greater Mark of Attack Damage
3: 5245: Greater Mark of Attack Damage
4: 5245: Greater Mark of Attack Damage
5: 5245: Greater Mark of Attack Damage
6: 5245: Greater Mark of Attack Damage
7: 5245: Greater Mark of Attack Damage
8: 5245: Greater Mark of Attack Damage
9: 5245: Greater Mark of Attack Damage

->

1: 5245: Greater Mark of Attack Damage x9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
foreach ( $r2->{$id}->pages as $page ) {

    $prev_id = "";
    $prev_count = 0;

    echo "<br>".$page->name.":<br>";
    foreach ( $page->slots as $slot ) {
        $id = $slot->runeId;
        $details = $result->$id->{'name'};

        if($prev_id!=$id)
        {
            if($prev_id!="")
            {
                echo " x".$prev_count;
                echo "<br/>";
                $prev_count = 0;
            }
            echo $slot->runeSlotId.": ".$slot->runeId.": ".$details;
        }
        $prev_count += 1;
        $prev_id = $id;
    }

    echo " x".$prev_count;
    echo "<br/>";
}
```

Comment: The only issue is that it prints the `x...` for the name as well. screenshot: http://i.gyazo.com/f7f9612bfe42e17d628e3ec878b7e56b.png

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$lastId = 0;
$counter = 1;
foreach ( $r2->{$id}->pages as $page ) {
    echo "<br>".$page->name.":<br>";
    foreach ( $page->slots as $slot ) {
        $id = $slot->runeId;
        $details = $result->$id->{'name'};
        echo $slot->runeSlotId.": ".$slot->runeId.": ".$details.(($count==0)?(''):(' x'.$count));
        echo "<br>";

        if ($slot->runeId == $lastId) {
           $counter++;
        } else {
           $lastId = $slot->runeId;
           $counter = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
foreach ( $r2->{$id}->pages as $page ) {
    echo "<br>".$page->name.":<br>";
    $tempSlot; $tempOut;
    $count = 0;
    foreach ( $page->slots as $slot ) {
        $id = $slot->runeId;
        $details = $result->$id->{'name'};
        $tempSlot =  $slot->runeSlotId.": ".$slot->runeId.": ".$details;
        if ($count == 0) {
            $tempOut == $tempSlot;
        }
        if ($tempSlot == $tempOut) {
            $count++;
        } else {
            echo $tempSlot;
            if ($count > 1) {
                echo " x".$count;
            }
            echo '<br>';
            $count = 0;
        }
    }
}
```